# Not able to run SSIS PACKAGE by DOS commands

Tags: ssis, dos, package, command

I want to run a SSIS package in command prompt...
for that i used the command
dtexec/f "C:/Filename.dtsx"...but when i executethis command i am getting an error like 
"Product level is insufficient for the component "Data Conversion"...

but when i run the SSIS package in BIDS,it executed successfully...
why is that??
is it because of any installation problem??
Please help me this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post. [ssis-product-level-is-insufficient](http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2006/11/11/ssis-product-level-is-insufficient.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

yes this is because of installation problem...I have installed again and checked..it is working for me...You can check the previous link sent by Michael for your reference